# Join conditions ON vs WHERE

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

probably a dumb question, but why are these two mysql queries giving different results?

```
select * from table1 p join table2 m on p.mid=m.mid and m.onw=1

select * from table1 p join table2 m on p.mid=m.mid where m.onw=1
```

the former gives about 5 times more rows. doesn't the "and m.onw=1" limit the same way as the "where" clause in latter query?

the actual live query executed from phpmyadmin is:

```
select * from xcart_products p join xcart_manufacturers m on p.manufacturerid=m.manufacturerid and m.onwalmart=1 
 (197023 total)
```

versus

```
select * from xcart_products p join xcart_manufacturers m on p.manufacturerid=m.manufacturerid where m.onwalmart=1 
(38996 total)
```

UPDATE. seems to be a bug in phpmyadmin. if i use count(*) instead of * then results are same. perhaps count(*) causes less rows to be returned?

Comment: I would not expect a difference in output with INNER JOIN and I believe default JOIN in MySql is INNER JOIN. There would be a difference with LEFT JOIN however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should give the same number of rows regardless where you put your filter.

**First Query:** It will join 2 tables and filter  `m.onw=1`

**Second Query:** It will join 2 tables and later filter on `m.onw=1`

Comment: but it doesnt. i updated with the exact queries i'm using

Comment: Just one question if you just filter on onw=1. How many records you will get? I think that is your answer.

Comment: i filtered both ways. seems if i use count(*) instead of * then results are same. any idea why?

Comment: Can you specified like m.* and , p.* and check how many rows you will get>

Comment: p.* gives 197k rows.   p.*,m.* gives 39k rows.

Comment: Can you do something like  Select a.*  FROM (select * from xcart_products p join xcart_manufacturers m on p.manufacturerid=m.manufacturerid ) a WHERE a.onwalmart=1

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add it into join statement rather than adding it as where clause from the performance point it will be better